# Use Distinct With Sum?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I want to sum a few values using case statements.  My problem is compiler complains if I do not add a group by to the end of the query, which then that negates my Distinct, hah.  For example, in my sample below this returns 2 entries for `red12` even though 1 entry does not fit any of the criteria above, but the `Group By` messes me up!  How can I run this query and only return applicable results, i.e. what the `case statements` show?

```
Create Table #Bobsled
(
  [event] varchar(100)
  ,[time] decimal(18,4)
  ,employeeID varchar(25)
  ,name varchar(500)
)

Insert Into #Bobsled Values
('Walk', '16.32','red12', 'red arrow')
,('Eat', '5.12', 'red12', 'red arrow')
,('Run', '32.13','pink01', 'pink pig')
,('Walk', '2.12', 'bl81', 'blue fire')
,('Sleep', '8.12', 'gr99', 'green pony')


Select Distinct
employeeid
,case when [event] = 'Walk' then SUM([time]) else 0 end as walktime
,case when [event] = 'RUN' then SUM([time]) else 0 end as runtime
,case when [event] = 'Sleep' then SUM([time]) else 0 end as sleeptime
FROM #Bobsled
--only executes sucesfully with this 
GROUP BY employeeID, [event]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the Pivot operator for this query.  See the below.

```
DECLARE @Bobsled TABLE
    (
      [event] VARCHAR(100)
    , [time] DECIMAL(18, 4)
    , employeeID VARCHAR(25)
    , name VARCHAR(500)
    );

INSERT  INTO @Bobsled
VALUES  ( 'Walk', '16.32', 'red12', 'red arrow' )
,       ( 'Eat', '5.12', 'red12', 'red arrow' )
,       ( 'Run', '32.13', 'pink01', 'pink pig' )
,       ( 'Walk', '2.12', 'bl81', 'blue fire' ) 
,       ( 'Sleep', '8.12', 'gr99', 'green pony' );

WITH    CTE_Bobsled
          AS ( SELECT   *
               FROM     @Bobsled B PIVOT ( SUM([time]) FOR [event] IN ( [Walk],
                                                              [Run], [Sleep] ) ) AS PivotTable
             )
    SELECT  employeeID
          , Walk
          , Run
          , Sleep
    FROM    CTE_Bobsled;
```

Answer (score 5):

I think what you're looking for is an aggregate on `employeeID` where the `CASE` goes *inside* the `SUM()` aggregate function.

```
SELECT employeeid,
       SUM((CASE WHEN [event] = 'Walk' THEN [time] ELSE 0 END)) AS walktime,
       SUM((CASE WHEN [event] = 'RUN' THEN [time] ELSE 0 END)) AS runtime,
       SUM((CASE WHEN [event] = 'Sleep' THEN [time] ELSE 0 END)) AS sleeptime
FROM #Bobsled
GROUP BY employeeID;
```

This way, you get one result row per employeeID, basically pivoted on event.

Comment: The `ELSE 0` is there to avoid aggregating on NULL values, which is ugly and will produce a warning.

Comment: Yes, if there are zero rows with `event='Walk'` for some empoyees, the sum of all nulls will be null. The `ELSE 0` avoids that.

Comment: A condition `WHERE [event] IN ('Walk', 'Run', 'Sleep')` might be added as well. It might improve efficiency (or make it worse ;).

Comment: What's wrong with aggregating on NULL values?  For SUM there's a correct alternative to NULL, but there is not for AVG.  NULL is the correct value in this case.  `AVG((CASE WHEN [event] = 'Walk' THEN [time] ELSE ??? END))`